Can't open 24.04LTS
Since I upgrade a Dell PC to X-Ubuntu 24.04LTS I can't open it except by using the recovery system.
I do a boot-repair and nothing wrong was found.
Dell Inspiron 15
12th Gen Intel Core i5-1235U
A BIOS' update had been made at the end of this morning.
Thank you for helping !
Regards,

Up date from what? Any error messages? Need details.

no message during the upgrade from server and no error message during the different updates from servers
